# Fable javascript binding issues

Tags: javascript, react-native, f#, fable-f#

I am attempting to make a rudimentary react-native app using the patented fable interop so I can use F# to do the actual coding. The F# portion is so far going very well however I am having very big issues understanding how the interop with react-native packages works.

I wanted to try to setup a binding for https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator

This is the current code

```
    open Elmish
open Fable.React
open Fable
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
open Fable.ReactNative.Types

type ScreenOptions = 
    | Title of string
    | TabBarIcon of (bool*string -> ReactElement)
    | TabBarColor of string
    | TabBarLabel of string
    | TabBarAccessibilityLabel of obj
    | TabBarTestId of string

type ScreenProps = 
    | Name of string
    | Component of obj
    | Options of ScreenOptions

type NavigatorProps = 
    | InitialRouteName of string
    | ScreenOptions of ScreenOptions
    | BackBehavior
    | Shifting of bool
    | Labeled of bool
    | ActiveColor of string
    | InactiveColor of string
    | BarStyle of obj

type ITab = 
    abstract member Navigator : NavigatorProps list -> ReactElement
    abstract member Screen : ScreenProps list -> ReactElement 

type Globals =
    [<Import("createMaterialBottomTabNavigator", from="@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs")>]
    static member NavBar with get(): ITab = failwith "JS only" and set(v:ITab): unit = failwith "JS only"


let inline renderNavBar (navbar : obj) (props : NavigatorProps list) =
    ReactBindings.React.createElement(navbar, (keyValueList CaseRules.LowerFirst props), [])

let inline renderNavBarScreen (navbar : obj) (props : ScreenProps list) = 
    ReactBindings.React.createElement(navbar, (keyValueList CaseRules.LowerFirst props), [])
```

This just crashes with the error:

```
 TypeError: (0, _native.createNavigatorFactory) is not a function. 
(In '(0, _native.createNavigatorFacvtory)(MaterialBottomTabNavigator)','
(0, _native.createNavigatorFactory)' is undefined)
```

I am assuming there is something with how I import the library or how I render it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.